# Installing Argo Rollouts on Azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, argocd, argo-rollouts

I'm using [ArgoCD](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd) along with [ArgoRollouts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/) on my local cluster. Setting it up a local cluster is straight forward, download the binaries, set path for the binaries and execute `kubectl argo rollouts version`

However, I'm trying to install it on a new Azure Kubernetes cluster but unable to do, as per the [installation steps](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/installation/#manual) mentioned, the binaries need to be downloaded and set as the Env path but it is failing at `sudo mv ./kubectl-argo-rollouts-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kubectl-argo-rollouts` - *which is understood, but how do I overcome that?*

I've not come across any other way to install ArgoRollouts. There are documents available on [installing ArgoCD](https://www.buchatech.com/2021/11/get-started-with-argo-cd-azure-kubernetes-service/) but not ArgoRollouts.

Comment: Please check this document related about [ArgoRollouts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/installation/) installation

Answer (score 0):

We use Kustomize to generate our manifests for Argo Rollouts. We also use have Argo CD manage Argo Rollouts as a separate application.

```
> cat kustomization.yml
resources:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-rollouts/v1.2.1/manifests/install.yaml
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-rollouts/v1.2.1/manifests/dashboard-install.yaml
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-rollouts/v1.2.1/manifests/notifications-install.yaml

images:
  - name: quay.io/argoproj/argo-rollouts
    newTag: v1.2.1
  - name: quay.io/argoproj/kubectl-argo-rollouts
    newTag: v1.2.1

namespace: argo-rollouts
```

If you want to install manually (ie Argo CD not managing it), then you can navigate to the kustomization directory and run `kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -`